# XML AUTO queries return derived table references in 90 or later compatibility modes

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I am currently performing SQL server migration from 2005 to 2012. As the first step, I generated DMA report and observed that most of the Procedures that use XML Auto are part of that report.

**MSDN** gives the following info :

When the database compatibility level is set to 90 or later, FOR XML queries that execute in AUTO mode return references to derived table aliases. When the compatibility level is set to 80, FOR XML AUTO queries return references to the base tables that define a derived table.

Consider the following query, the output will vary in 2005 and 2012 (&later version)

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT a.id AS a, b.id AS b 
FROM Test a 
JOIN Test b ON a.id=b.id) AS DerivedTest 
FOR XML AUTO;
```

**2005** : `<a a="1"><b b="1"/></a><a a="2"><b b="2"/></a>`

**2012** : `<DerivedTest a="1" b="1"/><DerivedTest a="2" b="2"/>`

Now the question is, both 2005 and 2012 version gives me the same output

```
<DerivedTest a="1" b="1"/><DerivedTest a="2" b="2"/>
```

Need your help to confirm the affected Tsql objects needs to be remediated or not.

MSDN url : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/for-xml-auto-queries-return-derived-table-references-90-later-compatibility-mode?view=sql-server-2014&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2017

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I don't understand what your question is here. can you try to clarify what you are asking?

Comment: Hi @SeanLange My bad had some formatting issue. Can you check now

Comment: Here is my confusion. You say you get the same output but in your sample they are clearly NOT the same. And the only question you have asked if you need to fix them. I don't know, is it not working the way you want it to?

Comment: As per MSDN or DMA report, we need to modify the Proc in 2012 version. When I tried to create the same scenario, we observed that output is same in 2005 and 2012 version. Hope this helps.

Comment: Those two outputs you posted are not the same. Again...what are you expecting as an answer here? You seem to be asking if somebody thinks you need to fix what you say isn't broken. If is working correctly then I would argue quite strongly that you should leave it alone.